# ElasticSearch wildcard not returning when value has special characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, wildcard

I have an elastic search service that fetches when you type into a text input to then populate a table. The search is working (returning filtered data) correctly for all alphanumeric values but not special characters (hyphens in particular). For example for the country `Timor-Leste` if I pass in `Timor` as the term I get the result but as soon as I add the hyphen (`Timor-`) I get an empty array response.

```
const queryService = {
  search(tableName, field, term) {
    // If there is no search term, run the wildcard search with 20 values
    // for the smaller lists to be pre-populated, like "Gender"
    return `
{
  "size": ${term ? 200 : 20},
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "tablename": "${tableName}"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "${field}": {
              "value": "${term ? `*${term.trim()}*` : '*'}",
              "boost": 1.0,
              "rewrite": "constant_score"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
`;
  },
};
```

Is there a way I can modify my wildcard request to allow hyphens? The other response I've seen on here has suggested using `"analyze_wildcard": true` which hasn't worked. I've also tried to manually escape by putting a `\` before each hyphen with `.replace`.

Answer (score 5):

It all boils down to Elasticsearch [analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html).

By default, all `text` fields will be run through the [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), e.g.:

```json
GET _analyze/
{
  "text": ["Timor-Leste"],
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

This will lowercase your input, strip any special chars, and produce the tokens:

```json
["timor", "leste"]
```

If you'd like to forgo this default process, add a `.keyword` mapping:

```json
PUT your-index/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "country": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {             <---
          "keyword": {          
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then reindex your docs, and when dynamically constructing the `wildcard` query with the newly created `.keyword` field, make sure the hyphen (and all other special chars) is properly escaped:

```json
POST your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "country.keyword": {
        "value": "*Timor\\-*"    <---
      }
    }
  }
}
```